# having multiple language switchers in a single node for Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, multilingual, language-switching

So I am still getting the hang of drupal and i would like to know if this is possible.

I want to have 2 language switchers in my site. One is for the whole site. the other switcher will be exactly in one of my content types and it should only translate the content and nothing else.

So the main language switcher will translate the entire site based on URL. The second language switcher should only change the content. Is this possible? if so then what is the best way to achieve this?

I am using Drupal 9.

Comment: have you enabled the 'language' core module?

Comment: yep, it won't translate a single content it will translate the entire site.